# Regression or fit with an homographic or a linear fractional relation

Tags: regression, references, optimization, nonlinear-regression

This question is motivated by exploratory data analysis. I have a number of variables, related to a chemical reaction. Each variable is the  quantity of a chemical species produced in different conditions. Models for such reactions are complex, mostly unknown. Heuristically, species taken two-by-two exhibit:

- an increasing  linear behavior: they are produced at a proportional rate,
- a "bended" increasing behavior: they are produced together, one faster than the other (some fit parabolas to them),
- a seemingly hyperbolic behavior ($y\sim \frac{1}{x+\alpha}+\beta$): they are "concurrent",
- a dispersed behavior: their production does not seem related.

I have no experience in model selection, and  wanted to find a short path to assign each couple of variable a behavior.

The [homographic or a linear fractional function](http://users.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/HomographicRelation.html) is defined by:
$$y = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\,.$$
I have the feeling this could be a versatile function for regression: for monotonic relationships (either increasing or decreasing), linear or hyperbolic, with only $3$ actual parameters.
However, it may lead to nonlinear optimization. I have difficulties finding statistical literature on the subject.

1. Does this exist with other names?
2. What are major references on the subject, if they exist?
3. Are there inherent difficulties or caveats, which might prevent their use?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it would appear to be difficult to estimate such a regression with standard libraries/linear algebra-based methods (correct me if I'm wrong!). On the other hand, methods like (restricted) cubic splines offer a very flexible family of regression forms that can approximate many different forms of relationships. Cubic splines *can* be estimated with slight adjustments to standard linear algebra approaches.

Comment: Note that it really has only three parameters: one can be eliminated by constraining the determinant $ad-bc$ to be a unit.  Because it is nonlinear (in both the parameters and $x$), one would have to have a compelling reason to adopt it, such as an underlying theory suggesting it would be a good model. One such situation concerns projective transformations of map coordinates, in which both $x$ and $y$ are complex variables (and so $a,b,c,d$ are also complex).

Comment: @whuber I have corrected the number of parameters, and added more context. This is not projective geometry

Comment: If you would like to deny that it is projective geometry, you are only cutting off potentially fruitful answers and literature.  In effect, you are telling us you do *not* want your questions (1) and (2) to be answered!

Comment: @whuber  I have no reason to believe my data is related to projective geometry as can happen in stereo image processing. Yet such tool can help